# guestfs-xxxxxx VMs appearing in LibVirt (virt-manager)

Tags: virtualization, fedora, linux-kvm, libvirt, virt-manager

I have a KVM+LibVirt based hypervisor running on Fedora 22. I use virt-manager for managing the VMs over SSH.

For some reason I see "guestfs-00kxipwaewnkoq92" VMs appearing and disappearing at random. They generally don't exist longer than 10-20 seconds, so it's hard to inspect them, but I do know they don't have a VNC/Spice connection available for viewing.

Searching google for "guestfs- libvirt" and "guestfs virt-manager" doesn't yield and useful results. Does anyone know what these guestfs-xxxxxxxx VMs are and what their purpose is? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out; It's virt-manager itself. Virt-manager inspects VM harddisks to determine what OS is installed and what packages are installed. I can't find it well documented anywhere, but it seems to do this on all redhat/centos/fedora distros (or is virt-manager centos/redhat stuff?)
Either way, mystery solved!